# How to obfuscate a jar library in Android Studio?

Tags: android, jar, proguard, shuffle

I would like to obfuscate my .jar library in Android Studio. The most known way "Proguard" not shuffles .jar libraries according to my researches. Are there any way to shuffle a .jar library?

Comment: Is this library developed by you? if you have source code you can enable proguard obfuscation during gradle build process.

Comment: @NanPd Yes I did. I tried to use proguard file but it didn't work. Are there different way to shuffle a jar library?

Comment: When you say proguard didn't work means app crashing or build issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may use below properties. First try with minifyEnabled false and second step enable it.

```
 debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'}
```

Comment: I prepared  to 2 different version of jar libs. In first one I am using " useProguard true ". In second one didn't use proguard. After that I use these libs. in another project. There wasn't any differences between proguard enabled version of .jar and default .jar version when I click to lib. class.

Comment: useProguard uses proguard-rules.pro for it's work. If you rules file is empty it will not do anything. And minifyEnabled obfuscates your code. So you need to work progressively here. 1st update your rules to give some work for proguard. And then minifyEnabled.

Comment: Can you write a example proguard rule for shuffle everything?